# To check if an object is of type IQueryable or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have this statement:

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons= context.Persons.Where(/*SomeCondition*/);
```

It's declared as `IEnumerable<Person>` but it's instantiated with  `IQueryable<Person>`. I understand `IQueryable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.

For re-usability, I create a method that accept `IEnumerable` instead of two methods that accept `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` respectively:

```
public IEnumerable<PersonInfo> GetPersonInfo(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{ 
    persons = persons.Where(/*Some condition*/);
    IEnumerable<Person>  persons = persons.GroupBy(/*based on some property*/);

    /*Here i want check value type of persons is IQueryable or not*/

    return persons;
}
```

At the point of consumption, I have:

```
IQueryable<Person> persons= context.Persons.Where(/*condition*/);
IQueryable<PersonInfo> result GetPersonInfo(persons.AsEnumerable()).AsQueryable();
```

And for In-Memory Collection I have:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person> { new Person {}};
IEnumerable<Person> result = GetPersonInfo(persons);
```

At the `GetPersonInfo` method, how can i check `persons` is `IQueryable` or not?

Comment: Are you asking this as a means of finding out if the query has already been executed or not? Because that would not work, I could e.g. do `var test = myContext.persons.Where(x => x.Name == "Bob").ToList().AsQueryable()`. `test` would be an `IQueryable`, but the data would already have been enumerated.

Comment: Then my comment applies. You cannot know for sure whether it's in-memory or not based on its type, since you can cast an `IEnumerable` (in-memory) to an `IQueryable` while it stays in-memory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So easy to be the solution, but if I have understand your question correctly..

```
if (persons is IQueryable)
```